# Reading in data from a file, using fscanf (following a sepecific pattern)

Tags: c

I am trying to read in from a file, and I can't get the pattern of it right. Can someone tell me what I can do to get it working?

```
int main()
{

char name[20];
int age;
float highbp, lowbp, risk;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("data.dat", "r");

if(fp == NULL){

    printf("cannot open file\n\n");

}

while(fscanf(fp, "name:%s\nage:%d\nbp:%f\nrisk:%f", name, &age, &highbp, &risk) != EOF){


}
printf("Name: %s\n", name);
printf("%d\n", age);
printf("%f\n", highbp);
printf("%f\n", risk);

}
```

data.dat:

```
name:tom
age:32
bp:43.00
risk:0.0
```

Comment: that check on fp==NULL should return with error, now its proceeding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can't open the file it prints a message, but then continues. Instead it should return from main.

```
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("cannot open file\n\n");
    return 1;
}
```

fscanf will return the number of items parsed, so it's probably safer to stop reading when the number returned < 4 (not all the items could be read).

Presumably "data.dat" contains multiple records and each line has a line ending. This means that after reading the first record the next character in the file is the line ending for the "risk:0.0" line. You should end the fscanf template with `\n`.

This is because the second time it tries to parse the file, fscanf will see that character, which it isn't expecting (the fscanf template starts "name:"), so it will stop reading, and you'll get only the first record.

Comment: while(fscanf(fp, "name:%s\nage:%d\nbp:%f\nrisk:%f\n", name, &age, &highbp, &risk) == 4); did the trick

Answer (score 1):

You should change the "name" format specifier from `%s` to `%19s` to make it read at most 19 characters (+terminating '\0'). The way you have it now is a guaranteed failure in case someone gives you 20+ character name.

Answer (score -1):

> Can someone tell me what I can do to get it working?

I suggest you separate the functionality in different statements.
Don't try to cram all of the program functionality in 1 statement.

Your big statement is doing 3 things:

- it is reading data from file
- it is comparing the return value of `scanf` with `EOF`
- it is controlling when to stop reading

I suggest you do (at least) 3 different statements for the 3 different actions.

*Hint: comparing the return value of scanf only with EOF is a little too short*